# How to set currency format to the google spreadsheet cells using google Spreadsheet api 4 in c#

Tags: google-sheets-api

How to set currency format to the google spreadsheet cells using googleSpreadsheet api 4 in c#

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [NumberFormatType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#numberformattype) documentation for the number format of the cell wherein the actual format depends on the locale of the spreadsheet.

```
CURRENCY    |   Currency formatting, e.g $1,000.12
```

However, I can't find any documentation using c#. You can check this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ajdueYKcxyo) on how to change currency setting on Sheets.

This [tutorial](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm) and [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/286192/formula-for-updated-currency-exchange-rates-in-excel-or-other-spreadsheets) might also help.

> In Google Spreadsheets, getting current exchange rates is very easy with the built-in Google Finance querying function. E.g, to get the current rate for USD/EUR:
>
> ```
> =GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDEUR")
> ```
>
> This will work for all exchange rates Google Finance is tracking. See http://googledocstips.com/2011/03/09/how-to-calculate-foreign-exchange/